# SQLPLUS How can I fix this procedure to make it work correctly?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, pls-00103

Alright. I copied this code from class, but I must have been half asleep at the time because it doesn't actually work.

```
Create or replace procedure display_row is
    (p_itemid IN item.itemid%TYPE) is
    v_itemid Number;
    v_itemdesc varchar2(30);
    v_category varchar2(30);
Begin
    Select *
    Into v_itemid, v_itemdesc, v_category
    From item
    Where itemid = p_itemid;
    Dbms_output.put_line(v_itemid || ' ' || v_itemdesc || ' ' || v_category);
End;
```

How can I fix this procedure so that it actually works?

Here's the user errors:

```
LINE   POSITION TEXT
```

---

```
     2          6 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of
                  the following:

                     begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
                     <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> fo
                  rm
                     current cursor external language

     2         37 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of
                   the following:

                     return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `is` operator from first sentence

```
Create or replace procedure display_row is 
                                        <--Here
```

Your procedure should look like

```
Create or replace procedure display_row
    (p_itemid IN item.itemid%TYPE) is
    v_itemid Number;
    v_itemdesc varchar2(30);
    v_idemdesc varchar2(30);
Begin
    Select *
    Into v_itemid, v_itemdesc, v_category
    From item
    Where itemid = p_itemid;
    Dbms_output.put_line(v_itemid || ' ' || v_itemdesc || ' ' || v_category);
End;
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I feel silly for missing that, but now that I see it things are making a lot more sense.